# Angular request - pull dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Essentially this is what I'm trying to do:

[image: Angular Flow within my APP]

I'm making a APP that I have to call numerous amounts of dynamically generated JSON urls consistently. The only way I can get that 'JSON/Path' is by adding the url as a parameter within a DOM element. (Legacy system, I know not the most optimal solution here) After I get the request I will be factoring the data back into said div them recompiling the innerHTML.

What I need to know is;

- After Angular compiles the page and see's ng-controller how can I insert the jsrc (Json Path) into the Get request?
- Should I do this with a directive? Or can I somehow pick this information up when I go through my controller?

Comment: Can you work on the jsrc attribute or is it fixed ?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Absolutely, I can change that to what needs to be implemented. Might even be a better choice to go with 'data-src'?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/u52B5bVzdqs
This is what you are looking for. They say use directive ! I can help you with that if you want.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger that would be fantastic! So after looking at that.. Should I have the directive broadcast to the controller the path I need to call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it for you :

Add an attribute to your div : `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" jsrc="JSON/Path" urlGetter>`

```
directives = angular.module('MyApp', [])

directives.directive ('urlGetter', function() {
    return function(scope, elements, attrs) {
        scope.url = attrs.jsrc;
    }
}
```

and in your controller :

```
MyCtrl = function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get($scope.url)...
}
```

If you want more info about it : http://egghead.io/video/rough-draft-angularjs-useful-behaviors/

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks so much for the clarification on this Augustin much appreciated!